# How can i join two different selection queries with inner join

Tags: sql-server

Good day! I'm a beginner at doing queries I`m still learning it anyone can help me how to join two different selection queries this is my queries code.

Thank you in advance for helping me.

```html
Select * from 
( select
 mm.MemberId CLIENT_REFERENCE,
 mm.LastNM LAST_NAME, 
 mm.FirstNm FIRST_NAME, 
 mm.MidNm MIDDLE_NAME,
 mm.Address NO_STREET_SITIO_PUROK, 
 vm.VillageName BARANGAY_DISTRICT,
 cm.City CITY_MUNICIPALITY, 
 pm.Province PROVINCE,
 '0000' ZIP_CODE,
 mm.MemDOB BIRTHDATE,
 mm.MemGen GENDER,
 mm.ContNo CONTACT_NO, 
 '' ID_TYPE,
 '' ID_NO,
 mm.SSS [SSS/GSIS],
 '' PAGIBIG,
 '' PHILHEALTH,
 mm.TIN TIN,
 lm.LoanNo LOAN_REFERENCE,
 '10' CONTRACT_TYPE,
 'AC' CONTRACT_PHASE,
 'NA' TRANSACTION_TYPE,
 lm.LoanAmt LOAN_PRINCIPAL,
 wom.PrinAmt LOAN_BALANCE,
 lm.LoanDt DATE_GRANTED,
 ''DATE_DUE,
 lm.IntRate INTEREST_RATE,
 'Weekly' PAY_FREQ,
 lm.TotalInstNo TERM, 
 'PHP' CURRENCY,
 'ET' LOAN_PURPOSE,
 '04-01' BAR_TYPE,
 cd.IntCollAmt + cd.PrinCollAmt TOTAL_LOAN_BALANCE,
 '' CONTRACT_ACTUAL_END_DATE,
 '0' OVERDUE_DAYS,
 '' MONTHLY_PAYMENT_AMOUNT,
 '0'NO_OF_OUTSTANDING_PAYMENTS,
 cd.NoofInst - 1 AMOUNT_OF_LAST_PAYMENT,
 'Written Off Clients' Remarks
from MemberMst mm
 inner join VillageMst vm
on vm.VillageId = mm.Barangay
 inner join CityMst cm
on vm.CityId = cm.CityId
 inner join ProvinceMst pm
on cm.ProvinceId = pm.ProvinceId
---------------------------------
 inner join LoanMst lm
on lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
 inner join CollectionDtl cd
on cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
 inner join WriteOffMst wom
on wom.LoanId = lm.LoanId
 inner join BranchMst bm
on bm.BranchCode = wom.BranchCode
 inner join LoanSubPurposeMst lsm
on lsm.LSubPurposeId = lm.SubPurposeId
where wom.WriteoffDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' and cd.AccDate = wom.WriteoffDate
) as q1
inner join
(
 SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT cd.NoofInst,cd.CollAmt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cd.NoofInst DESC) rn
    FROM MemberMst mm 
    INNER JOIN LoanMst lm
        ON lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
    INNER JOIN CollectionDtl cd
       ON cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
    INNER JOIN WriteOffMst wom
        ON wom.LoanId = cd.LoanId
    WHERE
        mm.MemberId = '0050000404' AND
        lm.WriteoffDate = wom.WriteOffDate
) t
where t.rn = 2
) as q2
```

Any suggestion!

I got an error in this area.
[image]

Hi, Good day! I'm a beginner at doing queries I`m still learning it anyone can help me how to join two different selection queries this is my queries code.

Comment: Hello again, because the second half of the top level join returns just a single record, I think you can just drop that join and use the subquery in the `WHERE` clause of the first subquery.

Comment: The first (larger) query can return multiple rows,but the second (smaller) query is only for a single member and only one row can be output. Why on earth are you trying to combine these?

Comment: can you add some details sir @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Show us the outer join `ON` condition.

Comment: Sorry for that sir @Used_By_Already I'm a beginner on docorreing queries I don't know if this is correct

Comment: the problem is that your question tells us nothing about the actual result you want to achieve, and we have no idea what the data is in any of those tables.

Comment: I want to select all last 2 column transactions on table CollectionDtl the collamt

Answer (score 0):

Just to solve the error and not the actual result.

```
Missing ON clause to join q2 and q1.
```

should be

```
where t.rn = 2
) as q2 on q2.<field> = q1.<field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a suggestion, but it may produce unexpected results, use a `cross join`:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            mm.MemberId                    client_reference
          , mm.LastNM                      last_name
          , mm.FirstNm                     first_name
          , mm.MidNm                       middle_name
          , mm.Address                     no_street_sitio_purok
          , vm.VillageName                 barangay_district
          , cm.City                        city_municipality
          , pm.Province                    province
          , '0000'                         zip_code
          , mm.MemDOB                      birthdate
          , mm.MemGen                      gender
          , mm.ContNo                      contact_no
          , ''                             id_type
          , ''                             id_no
          , mm.SSS                         [sss/gsis]
          , ''                             pagibig
          , ''                             philhealth
          , mm.TIN                         tin
          , lm.LoanNo                      loan_reference
          , '10'                           contract_type
          , 'AC'                           contract_phase
          , 'NA'                           transaction_type
          , lm.LoanAmt                     loan_principal
          , wom.PrinAmt                    loan_balance
          , lm.LoanDt                      date_granted
          , ''                             date_due
          , lm.IntRate                     interest_rate
          , 'Weekly'                       pay_freq
          , lm.TotalInstNo                 term
          , 'PHP'                          currency
          , 'ET'                           loan_purpose
          , '04-01'                        bar_type
          , cd.IntCollAmt + cd.PrinCollAmt total_loan_balance
          , ''                             contract_actual_end_date
          , '0'                            overdue_days
          , ''                             monthly_payment_amount
          , '0'                            no_of_outstanding_payments
          , cd.NoofInst - 1                amount_of_last_payment
          , 'Written Off Clients'          remarks
      FROM MemberMst mm
      INNER JOIN VillageMst vm ON vm.VillageId = mm.Barangay
      INNER JOIN CityMst cm ON vm.CityId = cm.CityId
      INNER JOIN ProvinceMst pm ON cm.ProvinceId = pm.ProvinceId
      ---------------------------------
      INNER JOIN LoanMst lm ON lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
      INNER JOIN CollectionDtl cd ON cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
      INNER JOIN WriteOffMst wom ON wom.LoanId = lm.LoanId
      INNER JOIN BranchMst bm ON bm.BranchCode = wom.BranchCode
      INNER JOIN LoanSubPurposeMst lsm ON lsm.LSubPurposeId = lm.SubPurposeId
      WHERE wom.WriteoffDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
      AND cd.AccDate = wom.WriteoffDate
) AS q1
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT
            *
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  cd.NoofInst
                , cd.CollAmt
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cd.NoofInst DESC) rn
            FROM MemberMst mm
            INNER JOIN LoanMst lm ON lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
            INNER JOIN CollectionDtl cd ON cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
            INNER JOIN WriteOffMst wom ON wom.LoanId = cd.LoanId
            WHERE mm.MemberId = '0050000404'
            AND lm.WriteoffDate = wom.WriteOffDate
      ) t
      WHERE t.rn = 2
) AS q2
```

But once you see the results you will notice that all the rows have the same values for the 3 columns of the second query.

---

This is a second suggestion, based on what I think is probably intended. The second query now returns multiple rows that reference the MemberId, so we can now join using that column:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            mm.MemberId                    client_reference
          , mm.LastNM                      last_name
          , mm.FirstNm                     first_name
          , mm.MidNm                       middle_name
          , mm.Address                     no_street_sitio_purok
          , vm.VillageName                 barangay_district
          , cm.City                        city_municipality
          , pm.Province                    province
          , '0000'                         zip_code
          , mm.MemDOB                      birthdate
          , mm.MemGen                      gender
          , mm.ContNo                      contact_no
          , ''                             id_type
          , ''                             id_no
          , mm.SSS                         [sss/gsis]
          , ''                             pagibig
          , ''                             philhealth
          , mm.TIN                         tin
          , lm.LoanNo                      loan_reference
          , '10'                           contract_type
          , 'AC'                           contract_phase
          , 'NA'                           transaction_type
          , lm.LoanAmt                     loan_principal
          , wom.PrinAmt                    loan_balance
          , lm.LoanDt                      date_granted
          , ''                             date_due
          , lm.IntRate                     interest_rate
          , 'Weekly'                       pay_freq
          , lm.TotalInstNo                 term
          , 'PHP'                          currency
          , 'ET'                           loan_purpose
          , '04-01'                        bar_type
          , cd.IntCollAmt + cd.PrinCollAmt total_loan_balance
          , ''                             contract_actual_end_date
          , '0'                            overdue_days
          , ''                             monthly_payment_amount
          , '0'                            no_of_outstanding_payments
          , cd.NoofInst - 1                amount_of_last_payment
          , 'Written Off Clients'          remarks
      FROM MemberMst mm
      INNER JOIN VillageMst vm ON vm.VillageId = mm.Barangay
      INNER JOIN CityMst cm ON vm.CityId = cm.CityId
      INNER JOIN ProvinceMst pm ON cm.ProvinceId = pm.ProvinceId
      ---------------------------------
      INNER JOIN LoanMst lm ON lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
      INNER JOIN CollectionDtl cd ON cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
      INNER JOIN WriteOffMst wom ON wom.LoanId = lm.LoanId
      INNER JOIN BranchMst bm ON bm.BranchCode = wom.BranchCode
      INNER JOIN LoanSubPurposeMst lsm ON lsm.LSubPurposeId = lm.SubPurposeId
      WHERE wom.WriteoffDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
      AND cd.AccDate = wom.WriteoffDate
) AS q1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            *
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  mm.MemberId
                , cd.NoofInst
                , cd.CollAmt
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cd.NoofInst DESC) rn
            FROM MemberMst mm
            INNER JOIN LoanMst lm ON lm.MemberId = mm.MemberId
            INNER JOIN CollectionDtl cd ON cd.LoanId = lm.LoanId
            INNER JOIN WriteOffMst wom ON wom.LoanId = cd.LoanId
            WHERE wom.WriteoffDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
            ) t
      WHERE t.rn = 2
      ) AS q2 ON q1.MemberId = q2.MemberId
```

Comment: Hi, how can I select all last 2 column, not an individual.

Comment: You want query 2 columns but rows for each member as listed in the first query?

Comment: I want to select all last 2 column transactions in q2 I try the query in above but the collamt is all 100.

Comment: You provided q2, not me.

Comment: Can you change it that can select all last 2 column transaction it's so hard for my side because I'm still practicing doing queries if ok to you.

Comment: I just do not understand you. Forget about columns. What rows do you want in the q2 subquery if run by itself? **Try my second example above.** If that dos not work **I cannot help you further without sample data and expected result** read about "MCVE" here [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)